# google cloud firestore not working in 32bit JVM because of grpc-netty-shaded-1.19.0.jar

Tags: jvm, google-cloud-firestore, 32-bit

in 32bit jvm google firestore is not working/failed connect by throwing below exception

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to load any of the given libraries: [netty_tcnative_windows_x86_32, netty_tcnative_x86_32, netty_tcnative]

tried with other versions of grpc-netty-shaded.jar and other grpc libs

```
InputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("resource/java-firebase.json");
        GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount);
        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder().setCredentials(credentials).build();
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
```

the above code is working fine in 64bit jvm but failed in 32bit jvm only[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJuo0.png)

Comment: netty supports 64bit only, is there any other options or libs to connect with firestore from 32bit jvm???

Comment: If you're having a problem working with the Java SDK for Cloud Firestore, post an issue on its GitHub.  https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/tree/master/google-cloud-clients/google-cloud-firestore

Comment: @DougStevenson      posted there https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/issues/5232